# Why does Android WebView display a black screen?

Tags: android, webview

I've been banging my head against a wall this afternoon trying to get a WebView to work. Below is the code in the main class:

```
public class fkyougoogle extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 WebView webview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // WORKS
        //webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        // DOESN'T WORK
        //webview.loadUrl("http://www.theregister.co.uk");
        //webview.loadData("<html><body>hello</body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8");
        //webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://", "<html><body>hello</body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8", "http://www.theregister.co.uk/");

    }
}
```

This is Google's "Hello, Webview" example. If I use a WebView and try to access www.google.com then it works fine. If I try to access any other site then it fails including loadData and it just displays a black screen in the emulator. In the end I would like to read from a local file.

is included under the manifest tag and the XML schema is the same as the Hello Webview example.

Am I missing something obvious here? :(

Comment: This is for the latest SDK and Google APIs :)

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the call to setJavaScriptEnabled?

Comment: What does `adb logcat` say when the black screen shows up?

Answer (score 8):

Try changing

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

in your main.xml top level LinearLayout

It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had the same problem as the poster, this fixed it for me. Thanks Tyler!

Comment: You mean to say that the layout parameters have any influence on what urls the webview can load or not?

Comment: According to:

[ViewGroup.LayoutParams FILL_PARENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT)

This value is deprecated starting in API Level 8 and replaced by MATCH_PARENT

Answer (score 0):

Try `UTF-8` instead of `utf-8` for your latter two attempts. I have no problem loading http://www.theregister.co.uk using the same code -- try loading it in the built-in Browser app, and if that fails, you're perhaps encountering some sort of firewall/proxy issue.

[Here are a few projects](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/WebKit/) demonstrating simple uses of WebView, from one of my books.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem of a WebView being completely blank, but it my case it was caused by a missing android.permission.INTERNET uses-permission.